# Efeito em jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Como fazer um efeito em jQuery, que quando use o SCROLL os divs e os elementos aparecem em fadeIn, como nesse site: http://www.neotokio.it/

Comment: Você experimentou copiar o código fonte do próprio site? JavaScript é sempre visível, não?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Algo assim? [Exemplo no JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4p4Rk/1/)

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

        /* checar a localização dos elementos */
        $('.imagem').each(function (i) {

            var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + $(this).outerHeight();
            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

            /* se o objeto estiver completamente "scrollado" */
            /* pra dentro da janela, fazer o fade in */
            if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {

                $(this).animate({
                    'opacity': '1'
                }, 500);

            }

        });

    });
```

Lembre-se de setar a `opacity` dos objetos que você quer fazer fade in para `0`.

Comment: Obrigado era basicamente isso.

Comment: @dann caso esteja satisfeito com a resposta, por favor marque-a como aceita.

Answer (score 2):

O [SuperScrollorama](http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/), um plugin para jQuery, tem o que você precisa. Além disso, pude contar pelo menos outros 14 efeitos para o scroll no demo deles :-)

Comment: Tem algo mais relevante para responder? Respostas somente com links não são consideradas de boa qualidade aqui. http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42/queremos-respostas-que-contenham-somente-links

Comment: Perdão, mas eu não respondi apenas com o link. Só esqueci de colocá-lo no texto.

Comment: Só tem o link de importante. Não há uma informação relevante sobre ele. Não diz porque resolve o problema de quem perguntou. Como usá-lo, nada. Só o link e uma frase dizendo para a pessoa procurar lá. Isso não é considerado uma resposta aqui. Respostas precisam responder o que o autor pediu e ter um conteúdo relevante aqui. Para que possa ser aproveitado por outras pessoas no futuro.

Comment: Dê um exemplo de como usar esse plugin para o que o OP quer, e talvez o pessoal veja sua pergunta com bons olhos.

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar o plugin [jQuery.appear](https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear) .

```js
$('img[src]').appear(function(){
    $(this).show();
});
```