# jQuery, scroll, fadeIn elementos no scroll quando estão a 150px do 'bottom' da janela (viewport)

Tags: jquery, rolamento, transição

Sei que há plugins para isto mas não gostaria de usar a não ser se fosse mesmo necessário, neste caso não acredito que seja preciso. Gostava que uma serie de `divs` sofresse um fadeIn (uma de cada vez) quando o seu 'top' estivesse a 150px (por ex:) do 'bottom' da janela e fadeOut quando a menos de 150px. O meu código:

Tentei [assim](http://jsfiddle.net/4p4Rk/2/) mas não resulta bem, baseei-me [nisto](http://jsfiddle.net/4p4Rk/1/)

HTML:

```
...

<div id="projectImgs"><?php
    foreach ($imgsFromProject as $extraImg) { ?>
       <div class="wrapperExtraImg" data-image="<?php echo 'admin/' .$extraImg->image_path; ?>" style="background-image:url(<?php echo 'admin/' .$extraImg->image_path; ?>)"></div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>

...
```

CSS:

```
...

#projectImgs {
    font-size: 0;
    margin: 30px auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 900px;
}
.wrapperExtraImg {
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    width: 435px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 435px;
}

...
```

Comment: Seria legal editar a questão por um trecho do HTML de saída mesmo no lugar do código PHP, já que a questão é de jQuery. Facilitaria para testar o _snippet_.

Comment: Veja se é [isto](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2852/6560) que você está procurando e aí teremos um ponto de partida.

Comment: É isso sim, obrigado não encontrei nenhum exemplo. Mas que fizesse fadeOut a < 150 px também. @Bacco deixei assim de propósito para sabermos que não vai haver um numero pré-planeado de `<div class="wrapperExtraImg"...`

Comment: @evsar editei a pergunta tentei mexer com aquele codigo mas não resulta bem