# Como é feito esse efeito de scroll, que ao chegar em determinada posição, os itens começam a surgir?

Tags: jquery

Ja tentei fazer isso mas o problema é que não funciona direito, as vezes so funciona muito pra baixo ou muito pra cima, eu queria tipo, ao chegar em tal div, o efeito aplicasse pra esse div, alguém me da um help ?
Obs: Quero fazer com jquery.

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4126/129 é o mesmo que procuras basicamente. Ou seja, saber usar o croll para fazer animações, mostrar elementos, etc

Comment: Não sei se é o teu propósito mas tem bibliotecas jquery prontas que fazem isso, um exemplo: https://scrollrevealjs.org!

Comment: Você sabe qual o nome desse efeito ? parece que o efeito é esse mesmo que você me mostrou, mas quero criar eu msm com jquery, se eu souber so o nome acho que ja ajuda muito

Comment: Olha aqui acho que é exatamente o que está precisando http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2849/como-fazer-um-efeito-em-jquery-que-quando-use-o-scroll-os-divs-e-os-elementos-a @AverFenix